# Python - pd.DataFrame returning NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, fetch

I'm trying to fetch prices of three stock tickers from morningstar and put them into a data frame, but pd.DataFrame keeps giving me NaN values.

```
all_data = {}

for ticker in ['AAL', 'ALK','WTI']:
     all_data[ticker] = data.DataReader(ticker, 'morningstar', '2014-06-01','2016-06-13')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIHq4.png)

```
price = pd.DataFrame({ticker: data['Close'] for ticker, data in all_data.items()})
print(price.head(5))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMgq1.png)

Ideally I want the pd.DataFrame to return a data frame of four columns (date, closing price for ticker 1, closing price for ticker 2 and closing price for ticker 3) but it kept returning NaN values for the second and third tickers.

I'm wondering how can I fix the code to get intended results?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can make the code samples more readable by enclosing them in code format tags.  See the tools above the edit bar or check out the help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the dict value is dataframe, base on your image , so when you doing  `data['Close']` it will keep its index, different index concat will return NaN for miss match

```
all_data = {}

for ticker in ['AAL', 'ALK','WTI']:
     all_data[ticker] = data.DataReader(ticker, 'morningstar', '2014-06-01','2016-06-13')

price = pd.DataFrame({ticker: data['Close'].values for ticker, data in all_data.items()})
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the indexing might be the reason too, but how can I fix the issue so there won't be NaN values?

Comment: @CatherineZhang Adding .values(look at my answer)